# how to reduce or stop duplication of relation's entry in treeview

Tags: database-design, mysql

I want to create tree-view for display or show family member's relation. For this I created 3 tables i.e following.

```
familyDetails->[f_id,fname,lname]
relations -> [r_id,relation] .....//e.g father,mother,son,etc.
familyRelations ->[fr_id,fk_f_id1,fk_r_id,fk_f_id2]      //to show A is Father OF b.
```

Here problem is, if I say A is father OF B and C than it'll make one entry in `familyRelations` table. But here it will also create one more entry for B is daughter of A. So in opposite relation (e.g father->son or son->father, etc )
it'll create entry for all case.

So if there are N no of people in family then it'll create N * N entries in familyRelations  table.

How to define relationship with other members.
This flow is right or need to change? I am confused in this.

So how to solve this problem. 
Or is there any another way?

Comment: how many relations are in the relations table?

Comment: If you want to use family tree as the model for your objects, you won't need N*N entries in the `familyRelations` table because you should only care about relations between a pair of objects at 2 adjacent depths. Other relations can be inferred from the path you need to get from one node to another.

Comment: @DFord : more than 10

Comment: @randomA :Can you please explain it lil bit more ? ? ?

Comment: im not sure if this is what @randomA meant, but if you just insert the parents and possibly children of the for each record in the familyDetails table, from that you can figure out all the other relations.

Comment: @Kreya here is a lil bit more: You only record relationships: 'father of', 'mother of', 'son of', 'daughter of', 'marry', 'married'. Then in order to get a relation from two nodes, such as cousin, in the tree, you would walk from one node via 2 'son/daughter of' and then 2 'father/mother of'. In other words, find the paths and looks at the relations along it. If you really want details, it is very complicated. You may have multiple paths to get from one node to another, you will have to use only simple paths. Nevertheless, it is not hard, just takes lot of time dealing with all the cases.